# How to remove the input field around an image button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I made a clickable image button that triggers a pop-up upload window, but I can't seem to remove the button's input field from around the image. If you have any ideas on how to fix this issue, please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

This is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cr310msf/

HTML:

```
<button class="uploadshare"><img src=""></button>
<input type="file" />
```

CSS:

```
<input[type='file']{
width: 0; }
```

JS:

```
$('.uploadshare').on('click', function(){
$('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anchor instead. http://jsfiddle.net/cr310msf/1/

```
<a href="#" class="uploadshare"><img src=""></a>

$('.uploadshare').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
});
```